# Authenticating against active directory with windows authentication, and providing group-dependent views

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, windows, iis-7

**The Problem**

I'm an ASP.NET newb who has been given the task of creating a multi-user password management system for use within a secure intranet. Essentially the user will be automatically logged in via windows authentication, which will then provide them with an appropriate view depending on their group. For example, a user of group 'admin' would be able to access all password entries, and a user of group developers would be able to access all password entries belonging to users in the 'Developers' active directory group. Users should be able to create, update, and hide (delete) password entries.

**What I have so far**

So far I have essentially been figuring out what will and will not be impossible, and researching technologies. Windows authentication itself appears to be easy, however it breaks when I enable the role provider, which appears to be necessary for providing different views for users. By 'breaks' I mean specific users are still recognized, but entire groups are not.

The different views must be automatically served, and I have come up with two techniques to do this:

1. Checking the role (group) on the home controller, and serving the appropriate view. This would require a long list of messy 'if' statements, however.
2. Serve a common view and allow or disallow viewing certain elements according to group. This would require putting a lot of logic in a view, which is as I understand inappropriate.

There will be a password.cs model class which will hold all information on a password entry including which groups should have access to it. I cant really think of any other necessary models, as the user information would not need to be stored.

**Security concerns**

I understand that storing such sensitive data in a single location could be a recipe for disaster. Passwords will be appropriately encrypted using pre-exising libraries which I have access too. I will have help with this area. Also, passwords will not be view-able as plain text on the system to avoid shoulder-surfing, but will be displayed as asterisks and will be copy-able to the users clipboard.

**My questions**

Essentially I would like some advice on how to structure the system and the most simple ways to enable active directory authorization with windows authentication. I would like some advice on how to provide the appropriate view for the user, and how the different areas should fit together. I am not expressly asking for any help with the password security side of things, but any insight or discussion would be warmly welcomed. Essentially, I would very much appreciate any help, links to tutorials, or suggested readings.

**My tools**

At my disposal I have Visual studio professional 2010, MVC 4.0 and .NET framework 4.0, and standard (non-admin) access to the server.

I will be able to give experimental code which I currently have in place tomorrow (It's 22:30 GMT, I'll be back in the office tomorrow morning). Let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Are you not using a database? The series of IF statements is not required--storing the user/group information lends itself naturally to a database. In a pinch, use a text file!

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented two solutions where I had to integrate MVC with Active X Directory. There are multiple solutions (e.g. Security Application Block from Enterprise Library). However, I ended up using AzMan and the RoleManagerAzManProvider. I ended up with this combination because I did not need to deploy any additional libraries.

I started with this article: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649313.aspx][1]

Even though it is written for ASP.NET, I was able to use it for MVC. I placed my XML Local Policy Store underneath app_data and configured the web config

```
<add name="LocalPolicyStore" connectionString="msxml://~/app_data/MyPolicyStore.xml" />
```

This worked out nicely for me because the Policy Store allowed me to define Application Roles and, when deployed at my client, map those roles to AD Accounts.

After that, I implemented a custom Authorize Attribute that I registered in the Global filters. This is where I made the decision which page the user would be redirected when they logged into the app. Finally, I used the standard Authorize Attribute on controllers based on group names.

I have thought about writing a set of Custom Editor Templates and Display Templates that would take roles into account so that I can render different UI for controls based on the User's application role (render a span instead of input).

Although your application is probably already written, I hope this helps.

Chuck